# How to dynamically create kafka producers

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, pykafka

first I am doing baby steps in python and kafka, So let's say I have a listA=[item1, item2, item3] and every item of listA is a `producer` on a topic. Now what I want is to dynamically add/remove items to listA and became immediately producers also every item should run on it's own thread as they should be independent.

So basically I am trying to scale the application.

so far I tried to hard code every producer item and run it in its own terminal

each Item

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
import json
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
import time


input_file = open('./data/item1.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
coordinates = json_array['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']

# Generate uuid


def generate_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid4()


# Kafaka producer
client = KafkaClient(hosts="localhost:9092")

topic = client.topics['test_kafka2']
producer = topic.get_sync_producer()


# Generate all coordinates
def generate_coordinates(coordinates):
    # new_coordinates = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(coordinates):
        data = {}
        data['class'] = 201
        data['key'] = str(data['class']) + '_' + str(generate_uuid())
        data['time_stamp'] = str(datetime.utcnow())
        data['longitude'] = coordinates[i][0]
        data['latitude'] = coordinates[i][1]
        message = json.dumps(data)
        producer.produce(message.encode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(1)

        # If item reaches last coordinaates
        if i == len(coordinates)-1:
            coordinates = coordinates[::-1]
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
    # return new_coordinates


generate_coordinates(coordinates)
```

Comment: What was the outcome of your attempt? Did you get any errors? or did you get some output but not the desired one? Could you please share some details?

Comment: It works fine, I am just unable to scale it right now @Lalit